# HTML canvas displays image with incorrect colors in firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, canvas

I have noticed an issue with displaying images in an HTML canvas in firefox and am wondering if there is any solution.

In firefox, I find that when I attempt to display an image with a canvas, the image appears slightly more faded than it should. The same code in chrome, however, displays the image correctly. Is there any solution to have the colors appear exactly as they should in firefox?

Tested in firefox version 79.0

The image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TmzIT.png

The code:

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

const img = new Image();

img.onload = () => {
  const {
    width,
    height
  } = img;

  canvas.width = width;
  canvas.height = height;
  canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);
}

img.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/TmzIT.png";
```

```css
#canvas {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(5);
  image-rendering: pixelated;
  image-rendering: -moz-crisp-edges;
  image-rendering: crisp-edges;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

How it displays in Firefox:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qtheG.png

How it displays in Chrome:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHh28.png

Comment: Try with chrome to check if Firefox If faulty and update your browser to the latest version of the type

Comment: I have tried with chrome, it displays the image properly, and firefox is currently up to date (v79.0). It could be a bug, I wanted to know if anyone had a fix.

Comment: Tried in newest firefox and chrome. No difference.

Comment: No, contact Firefox instead and drop as a bug

Comment: @Qudusayo what are you talking about?

Comment: @therealguy a fix to what? can you explain what you mean by *"faded"*? Any screenshot comparison?

Comment: `#191d26` in both browsers. same color, same shape...

Comment: Can you explain what you see differently in your two screenshots? They are exactly the same. Same color, not faded nothing.

Comment: My mistake, the color in chrome is actually #191D26 and the color in firefox is #1F222A, however my issue still stands

Comment: The image has an sRGB IEC61966-2.1 color palette defined, but it's not embedded. Canvas currently doesn't support color profiles and browsers will indeed behave differently here, e.g Chrome is actively working on [this proposal](https://github.com/WICG/canvas-color-space), Firefox has some `gfx.color_management_...` flags available in `about:config`, and Safari will probably mess with the monitor's color-profile to make something "smart". All this to say that the best you can do is to use a standard color type in your png, like RGB: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yog91.png